# how does jquery encode and decode work

Tags: jquery, html-encode

I found following code for encode and decode html, but don't know how does it work.
Can anyone explain it with the jquery source code?

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess they are working fine if `Encode` means converting `HTML` to `plain text`.

And `Decode` means the other way round.

And if it is the opposite you are expecting, then just interchange the name of `function`